# Apache Ignite: "Blocked system-critical thread has been detected" exception in partition-exchanger

Tags: ignite

I've got an Apache Ignite cluster made of 6 nodes. Occasionally, after a couple of hours of running, a number of the exceptions like below are recorded in the log and the node stops. I don't use event handlers or pub/sub handlers in the affected service. What could cause these exceptions? And does it means anything that the "partition-exchanger" thread is always mentioned in these error messages?

```
 Jul 01, 2019 5:23:10 PM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger error
SEVERE: Blocked system-critical thread has been detected. This can lead to cluster-wide undefined behaviour [threadName=partition-exchanger, blockedFor=61s]
Jul 01, 2019 5:23:10 PM java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger log
SEVERE: Critical system error detected. Will be handled accordingly to configured handler [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=[SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED]]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, err=class o.a.i.IgniteException: GridWorker [name=partition-exchanger, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1562001729657]]]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: GridWorker [name=partition-exchanger, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1562001729657]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance$2.apply(IgnitionEx.java:1831)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance$2.apply(IgnitionEx.java:1826)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.worker.WorkersRegistry.onIdle(WorkersRegistry.java:233)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.onIdle(GridWorker.java:297)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.lambda$new$0(ServerImpl.java:2663)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$MessageWorker.body(ServerImpl.java:7181)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.body(ServerImpl.java:2700)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$MessageWorkerThread.body(ServerImpl.java:7119)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)
```

I use Apache Ignite for .Net v2.7 on a Linux container managed by Kubernetes. Thank you!

Comment: We are getting the same error, we are in version 2.7.5 only. Did you get this fixed? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: There are several reasons for this error, it depends on your application and network topology:

 1. High CPU load on any nodes, including high cpu load caused due to too many GC cycles running 
 2. Network or Network configuration issues (large timeouts for example)

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended to upgrade to 2.7.5 since it shows fewer of those spurious errors.

Otherwise, documentation section describes how to tune it: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/critical-failures-handling

Comment: We are getting the same error, we are in version 2.7.5 only. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Not yet but I did resolve the original problem -- thank you!

Comment: @AlexAvrutin could you share your solution? I've faced the same issue on new environment without any workload on Ignite and can't understand what's wrong.